# How to print output file size when use hive export data with command "insert overwrite directory"

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2, beeline, hiveserver2

I am using beeline to export data to hdfs with command:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE  DIRECTORY $export_tmp
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' 
   select * from xxx_table_name;
```

I want to set echo output file size such as 1024M.

Answer (score 0):

It can be many files if it runs on many mappers or reducers at the last vertex.

The easiest way is to execute in a shell

```
hadoop fs -ls <directory>
```

or

```
hdfs dfs -ls <directory>
```

You also can try to execute it inside beeline using `!sh`

```
!sh hdfs dfs -ls <directory>
```

Also maybe counters printed at the end of the job can be used, like HDFS: Number of bytes written (not sure is this figure correct or not)